# If $f(f(x))$ is linear, is $f(x)$ linear? If f(x) is closed on the set of natural numbers?

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic, linear-transformations, divisibility, functional-equations

If I have a function defined on the natural numbers $\mathbb Z_{>0}$, does $f(f(x))=ax+b$ imply that $f(x)=rx+q$, where $a,b,r,q$ are naturals? This came to mind in the context of a different problem, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Do u mean $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: oops, I meant to put the >0 subscript but $\mathbb N$ yes

Comment: I get that if $f(x$) is linear, then applying it twice will result in a linear transformation, but I don't see why it should be true the other way round ( $f(f(x))$ being linear resulting in $f(x)$ being linear), at least not obviously

Answer (score 10):

No: consider the function $f$ that swaps every odd natural number with its successor. Then $f\circ f=id$ but $f$ is not monotone.